# trouble looping through google places API with pagetoken in Go

Tags: api, go, google-api

Im having trouble looping through the Google Places API in Go.

Google's Places API returns 20 results max with a pagetoken parameter to add to the query to return the next 20 results until theres none left.

I currently am able to send a query request, return the json and output it in terminal, but when i try to loop back through and add the `pagetoken` parameter to the query, it runs but only returns the first page results again but with another page token. Any Idea what im doing wrong?

package main

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    // "os"
)

type GooglePlaces struct {
    HTMLAttributions []interface{} `json:"html_attributions"`
    NextPageToken    string        `json:"next_page_token"`
    Results          []struct {
        Geometry struct {
            Location struct {
                Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
                Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
            } `json:"location"`
            Viewport struct {
                Northeast struct {
                    Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
                    Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
                } `json:"northeast"`
                Southwest struct {
                    Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
                    Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
                } `json:"southwest"`
            } `json:"viewport"`
        } `json:"geometry"`
        Icon         string `json:"icon"`
        ID           string `json:"id"`
        Name         string `json:"name"`
        OpeningHours struct {
            OpenNow     bool          `json:"open_now"`
            WeekdayText []interface{} `json:"weekday_text"`
        } `json:"opening_hours,omitempty"`
        Photos []struct {
            Height           int      `json:"height"`
            HTMLAttributions []string `json:"html_attributions"`
            PhotoReference   string   `json:"photo_reference"`
            Width            int      `json:"width"`
        } `json:"photos,omitempty"`
        PlaceID   string   `json:"place_id"`
        Reference string   `json:"reference"`
        Scope     string   `json:"scope"`
        Types     []string `json:"types"`
        Vicinity  string   `json:"vicinity"`
        Rating    float64  `json:"rating,omitempty"`
    } `json:"results"`
    Status string `json:"status"`
}


func searchPlaces(page string) {
    apiKey := "API_KEY_HERE"
    keyword := "residential+bank+33131"
    latLong := "25.766144,-80.190589"
    pageToken := page
    var buffer bytes.Buffer

    buffer.WriteString("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=")
    buffer.WriteString(latLong)
    buffer.WriteString("&radius=50000&keyword=")
    buffer.WriteString(keyword)
    buffer.WriteString("&key=")
    buffer.WriteString(apiKey)
    buffer.WriteString("&pagetoken=")
    buffer.WriteString(pageToken)

    query := buffer.String()

    // PRINT CURRENT SEARCH
    println("query is ", query)
    println("\n")


    // SEND REQUEST WITH QUERY
    resp, err := http.Get(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // CLOSE THE PRECLOSER THATS RETURNED WITH HTTP RESPONSE
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    res := GooglePlaces{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &res)

    var listings bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < len(res.Results); i++ {
        listings.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i + 1))
        listings.WriteString("\nName: ")
        listings.WriteString(res.Results[i].Name)
        listings.WriteString("\nAddress: ")
        listings.WriteString(res.Results[i].Vicinity)
        listings.WriteString("\nPlace ID: ")
        listings.WriteString(res.Results[i].PlaceID)
        listings.WriteString("\n---------------------------------------------\n\n")
    }
    listings.WriteString("\npagetoken is now:\n")
    listings.WriteString(res.NextPageToken)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(listings.String())
    fmt.Printf("\n\n\n")

    // LOOP BACK THROUGH FUNCTION
    searchPlaces(res.NextPageToken)

}

func main() {
    searchPlaces("")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the [documentation for Google Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) they state:

> There is a short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become valid.

But in your code you immediately send a request with the new token.

Adding a sleep for a few seconds before using the token solves the problem for me. I changed your code to

```
    if res.NextPageToken != "" {
        time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
        searchPlaces(res.NextPageToken)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No more pagetoken, we're done.")
    }
```

Unfortunately there's no documentation about for how long a token is valid.

Comment: Worked Perfect! Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Question though... I'm now noticing that it will only return a max of 3 sets of results. I've only been able to top out on 60 results on some basic searches like "fast+food". Any Idea on how to bypass this?

Comment: Google always caps the number of results to 60. That means you will atmost get 3 pages of results. Look at the documentation I linked to in the answer, it is explained there.